# Addition of Temperature Units

Tags: temperature, units, si-units

I would like to know how does the addition of temperatures works. In school, we have been taught that we should convert degrees Celsius to Kelvin unit first and then the sum will be converted back to degrees Celsius. What if we add zero with zero, the two units are in degrees Celsius which are not absolute.

0°C = 273.15 K
0°C + 0°C = ?

*Convert 0°C to K*: 273.15 K

273.15 K + 273.15 K = 546.3 K

*Convert 546.3 K to °C* = 543.3 - 273.15 = **273.15°C**

Is this correct? When looking at it, 0°C is cold and 0°C is cold too, if we add these two, shouldn't it be colder too? I have a feeling it's wrong. You're probably laughing right now, lol!

Sorry, just asking for a dumb person, myself. (lol)

Comment: In what context is this being done?  I'm having trouble thinking of a situation where adding temperature makes sense.  You already mention part of the issue in the question.  0°C is cold, because of the temperature difference between that and body temperature.  Most situations involve temperature difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add temperatures?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132720/)

Comment: In some equations involving temperature, it is better to use a scale that uses absolute zero as a baseline.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take two temperatures, both in Celsius, $x_1^{0}\text{C}$ and $x_2^{0}\text{C}$.

Expressed in $\text{Kelvin}$, these would be:
$$T_1=x_1+273.15\text{K}$$
$$T_2=x_2+273.15\text{K}$$

Now, I know of relatively few examples where temperatures would have to be added$^*$ but calculating a **temperature difference** $\Delta T$ is very common, say:

$$\Delta T=T_2-T_1=x_2+273.25-(x_1+273.25)=x_2-x_1$$

So here we see that starting from $^{0}\text{C}$ or starting from $\text{K}$ makes **no difference to the outcome** because the $273.15$ drops out.

---

But now lets take the **ratio** of the two temperatures (common in thermodynamics):
$$\frac{T_2}{T_1}$$

Here starting from $^{0}\text{C}$ or starting from $\text{K}$ does not yield the same result because:

$$\frac{x_2+273.15}{x_1+273.15} \neq \frac{x_2}{x_1}$$

For ratios **we must** use $\text{K}$ consistently to get the correct result.

---

$^*$ re addition, it's certainly possible to add *enthalpies*. Say we mix some hot water with some cold water in an adiabatic process. The end temperature $T_3$ can be found from:

$$m_1c_pT_1+m_2c_pT_2=(m_1c_p+m_2 c_p)T_3$$

Here, if we consistently use $\text{K}$ we get the result in $\text{K}$ and if we consistently use $^0\text{C}$ we get the result in $^0\text{
C}$.

Note that in the special case where $m_1=m_2$ then:

$$T_3=\frac{T_1+T_2}{2}$$

Comment: You could also say that using Kelvin will not lead to the case where you have to divide by 0.

Comment: Except... $0 K$ can never be reached!

Answer (score -1):

I think you have misunderstood the purpose of the advice you have been given.

If you have a quantity of water, say, at a given temperature, say 25 degrees Celsius, and you increase its temperature by 10 degrees Celsius, you can simply add the two numbers and say that its final temperature is 35 degrees Celsius. There is no need for any conversion.

However, if you want to know what temperature you will have if you take a quantity of water at 25 degrees Celsius, and another quantity at 35 degrees Celsius, then you need to convert them to degrees Kelvin before you perform your calculations.

The reason is that the Kelvin scale is an absolute one, whereas Celsius is relative to the freezing point of water. That might be a difficult distinction to appreciate, so I will try to illustrate with an example. Suppose you have an iceberg that sticks up 20 metres above sea level. Its total height will be much greater, because most of it is underwater and is overlooked when you measure the height from sea level. The height above sea level might be a handy reference for some purposes- for example, if you put a flagpole of length 5m on top of the iceberg you can calculate that the top of the flagpole will be 25m above sea level. But for other purposes the height above sea level can't be used, and you must consider the full depth of the iceberg (for calculating its volume, say).

Comment: "_However, if you want to know what temperature you will have if you take a quantity of water at 25 degrees Celsius, and another quantity at 35 degrees Celsius, then you need to convert them to degrees Kelvin before you perform your calculations._"  How so?  Most calculations would be driven by the temperature difference; and difference is equivalent when going between K and °C.